# Emoticonos en RPI3 ( Raspbian )

Tags: javascript, mysql, mariadb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

[image: Q]

Quiero pasar emoticonos a una base de datos mariaDB, al momento de pasarlos a la DB se convierten en "????" y si intento hacer un log a consola me sale la imagen adjuntada. Hay algun modo de implementar los emoticonos en la raspberry 3 (  Distro: Raspbian )?

Comment: que juego de caracteres tiene configurada tu base de datos?

Comment: Mi base de datos usa utf8mb4_general_ci